# Filtering a listview based on fields not displayed in listview

Tags: android, listview, object, android-arrayadapter

I currently have an app that grabs a json file from the internet, parses through it and creates and item object from it.  Items have the following fields:  type (image, text), and data (this is a url if the item is type image or a string of text if the item type is text)

When the app first loads the list displays a mix of all the items both types text and images.  If the item is an image, just the image is displayed in the list item in the listview, if it's text then the text is displayed.

What I need it to do(and am having a problem with) is I need it so that when the user selects from the menu "Image Only"  it will only show the objects that have the type "image" in the listview and hide the items that have type "text", if they select "Text Only", then it filters out all the image list items and only displays the items of type "text". If they select "All" it should display the default just as it does when the app first loads.

I do not display this object's type field on the listview anywhere, just the data field of the object which will either be an image loaded from a url or text.  It seems every filtering example I come across is when someone types text it filters the list but that text is displayed in the list and is visible in the list where what I need to filter for is not visible on the list..I'm not quite sure how to accomplish what I need.  Does anyone have any ideas? Hopefully I explained that well enough

Edit:  This is what I have so far.  Now, When I select Images from the menu it works, when I select Text from the menu it works, When I toggle back to all it's blank and mitems.size is zero even though I never removed anything from it.

on Create:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tvNoInet=(TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        getData theJsonData = new getData();
        theJsonData.execute();
    }

    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    customAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list,mItems);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mItems.get(position).getmType().toString().equals("text")){
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyWebView.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection, try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            if (mItems.get(position).getmType().toString().equals("image")){
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FullImage.class);
                in.putExtra("imageURL",mItems.get(position).getmData().toString());
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

My Options menu where they select from one of the options (All, Images, Text)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.all) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.clear();
        customAdapter.addAll(mItems);
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.images) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.clear();
        customAdapter.addAll(mImageItems);
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.text) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.clear();
        customAdapter.addAll(mTextItems);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My task that grabs the json, parses it, creates the object and then adds it to mItems, if type is image also adds it to mImageItems and if type is text adds it to mTextItems.

```
public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String jsonStr = null;
    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://host/data.json");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            jsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MAIN", "Error ", e);
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        try {

            JSONArray itemsArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            String itemID=null;
            String itemType=null;
            String itemDate=null;
            String itemData=null;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonItem=itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if (jsonItem.has("id")){
                    itemID=jsonItem.getString("id");
                }
                if (jsonItem.has("type")){
                    itemType=jsonItem.getString("type");
                }
                if (jsonItem.has("date")){
                    itemDate=jsonItem.getString("date");
                }
                if (jsonItem.has("data")){
                    itemData=jsonItem.getString("data");
                }
                Item myItem=new Item(itemID,itemType,itemDate,itemData);
                mItems.add(myItem);
                if (itemType.equals("image")){
                    mImageItems.add(myItem);
                }
                else if (itemType.equals("text")){
                    mTextItems.add(myItem);
                }




            }
            Log.e("ALL SIZE: ", String.valueOf(mItems.size()));
            Log.e("TEXT SIZE: ", String.valueOf(mTextItems.size()));
            Log.e("IMAGE SIZE: ", String.valueOf(mImageItems.size()));
        } catch (JSONException jsone) {
            jsone.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Json Data");
        }
```

And finally my adapter:

```
class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>  {
   private List<Item> items;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {

        super(context, resource, items);

        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = null;
        TextView tn = null;
        ImageView img = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        }
        else {
            v=convertView;
        }

        Item p = items.get(position);
        tn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            if (p.getmType().equals("image")) {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(p.getmData()).error((R.drawable.placeholder_error)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).resize(90,0).into(img);
                tn.setText("ID: " + p.getmID()+"\nTYPE: " + p.getmType() +"\nDate: " + p.getmDate()+ "\nDATA: " +  p.getmData());
            } else {
                img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tn.setText("ID: " + p.getmID()+"\nTYPE: " + p.getmType() +"\nDate: " + p.getmDate()+ "\nDATA: " +  p.getmData());
            }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now when the app loads the mixed list is showing all the items, If I select "Images" from the menu then only the image types are showing in the list, if I select "Text"  only the Text items are showing and I can toggle back and forth between Image and text fine.  However, when I select "All" again the list is blank and mItems.size is 0.  I'm over my head with this one.  haha  A way I found around it was when I'm adding the Item object to the list, I have a 4th list called mAllItems that basically gets set exactly the same as mItems so where I do mItems.add(myItem);  the next line is mAllItems.add(myItem)and in the menu selection I just set All to mAllItems.  I know I'm probably doing this all wrong but you have to learn somehow right?

Comment: Did you try just changing the dataset of the adapter?

Comment: I do not know how to do that.  I'm still learning and this is the first app that I'm using a listview with adapters and using objects to populate the list.  Is there a way to set the adapter to all items in mItems where the type equals one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're very close.

You already have three lists.  Since the adapter is the model for the `ListView`, it would make more sense to have those lists in the adapter.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public enum ListMode {
        IMAGES_AND_TEXT,
        IMAGES_ONLY,
        TEXT_ONLY
    }

    private ListMode mListMode = ListMode.IMAGES_AND_TEXT;

    private List<Item> mItems;

    private List<Item> mImages;

    private List<Item> mTexts;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        switch (mListMode) {
            case IMAGES_AND_TEXT:
                return mItems == null ? 0 : mItems.size();
            case IMAGES_ONLY:
                return mImages == null ? 0 : mImages.size();
            case TEXT_ONLY:
                return mTexts == null ? 0 : mTexts.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        switch (mListMode) {
            case IMAGES_AND_TEXT:
                return mItems == null ? null : mItems.get(position);
            case IMAGES_ONLY:
                return mImages == null ? null : mImages.get(position);
            case TEXT_ONLY:
                return mTexts == null ? null : mTexts.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;    // not really used
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = null;
        TextView tn = null;
        ImageView img = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        } else {
            v=convertView;
        }

        Item p = items.get(position);
        tn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        if (p.getmType().equals("image")) {
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(p.getmData()).error((R.drawable.placeholder_error)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).resize(90,0).into(img);
            tn.setText("ID: " + p.getmID()+"\nTYPE: " + p.getmType() +"\nDate: " + p.getmDate()+ "\nDATA: " +  p.getmData());
        } else {
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tn.setText("ID: " + p.getmID()+"\nTYPE: " + p.getmType() +"\nDate: " + p.getmDate()+ "\nDATA: " +  p.getmData());
        }
        return v;
    }

    /**
     * Call this when the filter is selected, e.g.
     * <code>mAdapter.setListMode(ListMode.IMAGES_AND_TEXT);</code>
     * @param listMode
     */
    public void setListMode(ListMode listMode) {
        mListMode = listMode;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * After you receive the JSON, call this method to add the items to the adapter.
     * @param items
     */
    public void setItems(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mImages = new ArrayList<>();
        mTexts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Item item = new Item(jsonArray.get(i));
            mItems.add(item);
            if (item.isImage()) {
                mImages.add(item);
            }
            if (item.isText()) {
                mTexts.add(item);
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Instantiate your adapter like this:

```
    .
    .
    .
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    customAdapter = new ListAdapter();
    myListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    .
    .
    .
```

When your `AsyncTask` runs, set the items on your adapter:

```
        .
        .
        .
        JSONArray itemsArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        customAdapter.setItems(itemsArray);
        .
        .
        .
```

Change your view from the menu like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case R.id.all:
            item.setChecked(true);
            customAdapter.setListMode(ListMode.IMAGES_AND_TEXT);
            return true;

        case R.id.images:
            item.setChecked(true);
            customAdapter.setListMode(ListMode.IMAGES_ONLY);
            return true;

        case R.id.text:
            item.setChecked(true);
            customAdapter.setListMode(ListMode.TEXT_ONLY);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Also, I would add a constructor to your `Item` class that takes a `JSONObject`:

```
    public Item(JSONObject jsonItem) {

        String itemID=null;
        String itemType=null;
        String itemDate=null;
        String itemData=null;

        if (jsonItem.has("id")) {
            itemID=jsonItem.getString("id");
        }
        if (jsonItem.has("type")) {
            itemType=jsonItem.getString("type");
        }
        if (jsonItem.has("date")){
            itemDate=jsonItem.getString("date");
        }
        if (jsonItem.has("data")){
            itemData=jsonItem.getString("data");
        }
        this(itemID,itemType,itemDate,itemData);
    }
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get it working I think because I'm using a ArrayAdapter.  I feel lost with this.  I kick off a async task that gets the json data, parses through it and puts it in the list of items.  So I have mItems, mImageItems and mTextItems.  so when I populate the list it looks like this: Actually I'm just going to edit my question with my code.

Comment: I have edited my question to include my code (if you can call it that)

Comment: Updated my answer based on your code.  I think it's more appropriate for the adapter to have the responsibility of managing three lists that are variations of a single list.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I got it to work with your help!  I'm reading through the code in the adapter now to try to understand how it all works better. The last thing I have to do is figure out how to save and restore the list state depending on which list is current.  I'm playing around with that now.

Comment: Ooh, that.  I often create a `saveInstanceState()` and `restoreInstanceState()` method for the adapter which will get called at the appropriate places in the activity/fragment.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: No luck, so far I have it saving the state but restoring it is causing an issue ( I know it's saving because when I examine customAdapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState) in the onCreate it's showing the right items based on selection but I'm having a hard time restoring it to the list view.  I created a gist showing the code  https://gist.github.com/graffixnyc/ed01679178c9f4fd99be

Comment: Ok, So I got it along further @kris-larson.  But now When the app loads everything is fine.  If I rotate the screen the current list is still being shown which is good.  However, now when I select an option after rotation the listview is blank if I select Images Only or Text Only.. If I select All then whatever the current list was before stays.. So if I selected images only and then select all, then images only list is displayed.  If I select Images only or text only then the list is blank: Code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298081/having-trouble-restoring-state-on-listview