# Having trouble restoring state on listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have an app that allows the user to select an option and a certain list is displayed in a listview.  I'm having issues with getting it to save and restore state.  I have a list_mode that gets set depending on which option the user selects.  so far I have it saving the state of the adapter but restoring it is causing an issue ( I know it's saving because when I examine customAdapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState) in the onCreate it's showing the right items based on selection but I'm having a hard time restoring it to the list view.  It will crash on restore. It crashes on getAllItems.clear and .addAll.  I have even hard coded this to one of the lists but it didn't work either.  When I comment that line out then it crashes in the main activity.  I'm a noob when it comes to Java and Android and am still learning.  I do not know how close or how far off I am.  Can anyone provide insight on what I'm doing wrong and how I can get it to work? Thanks

List Adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final String KEY_ADAPTER_STATE = "ListAdapter.KEY_ADAPTER_STATE";
public enum ListMode {
    IMAGES_AND_TEXT,
    IMAGES_ONLY,
    TEXT_ONLY
}

private ListMode mListMode = ListMode.IMAGES_AND_TEXT;

private ArrayList<Item> mItems;

private ArrayList<Item> mImages;

private ArrayList<Item> mTexts;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    switch (mListMode) {
        case IMAGES_AND_TEXT:
            return mItems == null ? 0 : mItems.size();
        case IMAGES_ONLY:
            return mImages == null ? 0 : mImages.size();
        case TEXT_ONLY:
            return mTexts == null ? 0 : mTexts.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int position) {
    switch (mListMode) {
        case IMAGES_AND_TEXT:
            return mItems == null ? null : mItems.get(position);
        case IMAGES_ONLY:
            return mImages == null ? null : mImages.get(position);
        case TEXT_ONLY:
            return mTexts == null ? null : mTexts.get(position);

    }
    return null;
}
public ArrayList getAllItems() {
    switch (mListMode) {
        case IMAGES_AND_TEXT:
            return mItems;
        case IMAGES_ONLY:
            return mImages;
        case TEXT_ONLY:
            return  mTexts;

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;    // not really used
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = null;
    TextView tn = null;
    ImageView img = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    } else {
        v=convertView;
    }

    Item p = getItem(position);
    tn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    if (p.getmType().equals("image")) {
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Picasso.with(parent.getContext()).load(p.getmData()).error((R.drawable.placeholder_error)).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).resize(90,0).into(img);
        tn.setText("ID: " + p.getmID()+"\nTYPE: " + p.getmType() +"\nDate: " + p.getmDate()+ "\nImage URL: " +  p.getmData());
    } else {
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tn.setText("ID: " + p.getmID()+"\nTYPE: " + p.getmType() +"\nDate: " + p.getmDate()+ "\nText Data: " +  p.getmData());
    }
    return v;
}


public void setListMode(ListMode listMode) {
    mListMode = listMode;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setItems(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {

    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    mTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        Item item = new Item((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
        mItems.add(item);
        if (item.getmType().equals("image")) {
            mImages.add(item);
        }
        if (item.getmType().equals("text")) {
            mTexts.add(item);
        }
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("list_items", getAllItems());
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("list_items")) {
        //ArrayList<Item> objects = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_ADAPTER_STATE);
        //getAllItems().clear();
        //getAllItems().addAll(objects);
        //mImages.clear();
        //mImages.addAll(objects);
    }
}
```

}

Main Activity:

```
myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    customAdapter = new ListAdapter();
    if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
        //When I put a breakpoint here I see it's getting the correct list
        customAdapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("list_items")) {
        //When I remove the .clear and .addAll it then crashes on this line
        myListView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("list_items"));
        myListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
    else{
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            getData theJsonData = new getData();
            theJsonData.execute();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tvNoInet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //Not sure what I should put here or if what I have is right
   customAdapter.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
//This is the code that sets the list_mode when the user selects an option
if (id == R.id.all) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.setListMode(ListAdapter.ListMode.IMAGES_AND_TEXT);
        myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.images) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.setListMode(ListAdapter.ListMode.IMAGES_ONLY);
        myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.text) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.setListMode(ListAdapter.ListMode.TEXT_ONLY);
        myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        return true;
    }
```

And my Item class:

```
public class Item implements Parcelable{
private String mID;
private String mType;
private String mDate;
private String mData;

public Item(String mID,String mType, String mDate, String mData)  {
    this.mType = mType;
    this.mID = mID;
    this.mDate = mDate;
    this.mData = mData;
}
public Item(JSONObject jsonItem) throws JSONException {
    String itemID=null;
    String itemType=null;
    String itemDate=null;
    String itemData=null;

    if (jsonItem.has("id")) {
        itemID=jsonItem.getString("id");
    }
    if (jsonItem.has("type")) {
        itemType=jsonItem.getString("type");
    }
    if (jsonItem.has("date")){
        itemDate=jsonItem.getString("date");
    }
    if (jsonItem.has("data")){
        itemData=jsonItem.getString("data");
    }
    this.mID=itemID;
    this.mType=itemType;
    this.mDate=itemDate;
    this.mData=itemData;
}


protected Item(Parcel in) {
    String[] data = new String[4];
    in.readStringArray(data);
    this.mID = data[0];
    this.mType = data[1];
    this.mDate = data[2];
    this.mData = data[3];

}

public static final Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Creator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public Item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Item(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Item[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Item[size];
    }
};

public String getmID() {
    return mID;
}

public String getmType() {
    return mType;
}

public String getmDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public String getmData() {
    return mData;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "ID='" + mID + '\'' +
            ", Type='" + mType + '\'' +
            ", Date='" + mDate + '\'' +
            ", Data='" + mData + '\'' +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    String[] data = new String[4];
    data[0] = mID;
    data[1] = mType;
    data[2] = mDate;
    data[3] = mData;
    dest.writeStringArray(data);
}
}
```

**UPDATE:  This is what the code looks like now.  When I select a certain list and then rotate the screen it's working.  It's staying on the currently selected list.  Now the issue is when they select a new list after the device has been rotated the listview is completely blank**

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
        customAdapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_LIST_VIEW_STATE)) {
            myListView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LIST_VIEW_STATE));
            myListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }

    }

    else{
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            getData theJsonData = new getData();
            theJsonData.execute();
            tvNoInet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRetry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tvNoInet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    customAdapter.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable(KEY_LIST_VIEW_STATE, myListView.onSaveInstanceState());


}
```

and my updated list adapter:

```
 private ListMode mListMode = ListMode.IMAGES_AND_TEXT;

private ArrayList<Item> mItems= new ArrayList<>();

private ArrayList<Item> mImages= new ArrayList<>();

private ArrayList<Item> mTexts= new ArrayList<>();

   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList("list_items", getAllItems());
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_ADAPTER_STATE, getAllItems());
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_ADAPTER_STATE)) {
        ArrayList<Item> objects = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_ADAPTER_STATE);
        getAllItems().clear();
        getAllItems().addAll(objects);
        //mImages.clear();
        //mImages.addAll(objects);
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the options menu that switches the list.  If I haven't rotated the screen yet this works.  When I rotate the screen and select a different list the listview is then blank.  If I select "All" which should display All items then whatever list I had selected before if restored. So If I selected Images Only at first, rotate the screen everything is displayed right, if I rotate the screen back and select Text Only or Images Only again, the list is blank, if I select "All" then whatever list I picked the first time (in this case Images Only) is displayed

```
if (id == R.id.all) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.setListMode(ListAdapter.ListMode.IMAGES_AND_TEXT);
        myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.images) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.setListMode(ListAdapter.ListMode.IMAGES_ONLY);
        myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        return true;

    }
    if (id == R.id.text) {
        item.setChecked(true);
        customAdapter.setListMode(ListAdapter.ListMode.TEXT_ONLY);
        myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can you be more specific? does crash mean NullPointerException? where are these listadapter members initilaized mListMode, mItems, mImages, mTexts

Comment: `savedInstanceState.putSerializable(ArrayList<Item>)` is an option if your Item's variables are simple data types.  I've used this before for simple implementations.

Comment: @k3b The crash happens on the onRestoreState in the adapter with a Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.ArrayList.clear()' on a null object reference error.  I have the error in a comment in the code above.  The default.  I will edit my question to include my full list adapter code.

Comment: Question edited to include more of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I got you into this mess....  :)

Something I do in situations like this is to pass in the saved instance state `Bundle` to the constructor for the adapter.  Since you made your `Item` class `Parcelable`, everything else should be easy.

```
    public ListAdapter(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            int ordinal = savedInstanceState.getInt("adapter_mode", 0);
            mListMode = ListMode.values()[ordinal];

            ArrayList<Item> items = 
                    savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_ADAPTER_STATE);
            if (items != null) {
                setItems(items);
            }
        }
    }


    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("adapter_mode", mListMode.ordinal());
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_ADAPTER_STATE, mItems);
    }
```

So with the saved instance state in the constructor, you don't need an explicit method to restore the adapter state.

```
    public void setItems(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            items.add(new Item((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)));
        }
        setItems(items);
    }

    private void setItems(List<Item> items) {

        for (Item item : items) {
            mItems.add(item);
            if (item.getmType().equals("image")) {
                mImages.add(item);
            }
            if (item.getmType().equals("text")) {
                mTexts.add(item);
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @kris-larson  I'm getting an error though on setItems(items) is expecting a json array  public void setItems(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at my answer and went - Oops.  Updated the answer.  You might have to correct some code, I didn't use an IDE so I probably botched something.

Comment: Ok @kris-larson I added the constructor and changed the setitems but now I'm getting an error in the Main activity on customAdapter = new ListAdapter(); when we first create the adapter.  Should I just create another constructor with no arguments?  Also then I'm confused on how I would pass the bundle to the listadapter to restore the state.  Like I said in my other question. I feel way over my head with this but I'm really trying to figure it out

Comment: no, just say `customAdapter = new ListAdapter(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: ok Thanks so much @kris-larson!  It's working now.  Now I have to try to understand it all because that's what's important to me and why I'm even doing this so I can learn.

Comment: Welcome to Android.  P.S. I'd be grateful if you could accept this answer as correct also.

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes if you call `ListAdapter.getAllItems().clear()` without calling `ListAdapter.setItems()` before

Cause: `ListAdapter.getAllItems()` may return null if `mItems`, `mImages`, `mTexts` are not initialized.

One workaround may be

```
public class ListAdapter extends ... {
    ...
    private ArrayList<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Item> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Item> mTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but it's still not working.  Now it crashes on: if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
            customAdapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            myListView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("list_items"));
            myListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }

It's crashing on:  myListView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("list_items"))
With an error: NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.widget.AbsListView$SavedState.getSuperState()' on a null object reference